# Downloading private Github repository with URL in vb.net Console application

Tags: vb.net, git, github

I need to remotely automatically update my vb.net application on other PCs every time I make changes to code on my machine. I have a private repository on Github where I store my code.

When the app detects that its build number is different than the most recent one, I want it to go to my Github repository, and to download a binary folder when it detects changes in build numbers. I need this done in a vb.net console application. Obviously, other machines cannot have Git installed on their computers, so git clone and other commands probably won't work.

Since I already keep my private repository up to date, I was wondering if there is a way to use it to update files for my application? I already tried creating a secret token with no luck, and any help would be very appreciated.

git clone https://@github.com/username/repo_name.git
This works on my machine and does not work on other machines that do not have git installed.

Just to conclude - I don't have a coding problem, just need a way to download a private repository to replace application files! I am fairly new to Github and it still confuses me sometimes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research, I came up with a solution. To make this work, you can use LibGit2Sharp (https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp/) and Microsoft.Alm.Authentication.

Just go and find & install them in the NuGet package manager. I created a simple console app to handle my application updating needs from the private Github repository, and the following code specifies credentials and clones repository into the desired folder:

```
Public Sub Clone(ByVal sourceUrl As String, ByVal workingDir As String)
    Dim cloneOptions = New CloneOptions With {
        .IsBare = False,
        .Checkout = True,
        .CredentialsProvider = New Handlers.CredentialsHandler(Function(a, b, c) New UsernamePasswordCredentials() With {
    .Username = "your@email.com",
    .Password = "your_password"
})
    }
    Repository.Clone(sourceUrl, workingDir, cloneOptions)
End Sub
```

A quick note - Microsoft.Alm.Authentication is the Git Credential Manager client that you can find on NuGet. It is released around 5 years ago and is still very poorly documented, but works If you want to clone your private repository for any reason. I also want to point out that LibGit2Sharp for .NET is worth checking out if you need to manage your repositories programmatically.

Cheers!